# How to get conda cuda version the same as the system cuda version?

Tags: pytorch

My system cuda version is 10.0, as shown by:

```
 nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sat_Aug_25_21:08:01_CDT_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.0, V10.0.130
```

I want to use 10.1 to install PyTorch 1.7.1 and PYG, so I did in a conda environment:

```
conda install pytorch==1.7.1 torchvision==0.8.2 torchaudio==0.7.2 cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch
```

Then I checked:

```
python -c "import torch; print(torch.version.cuda)"
10.1
```

But nvcc is still 10.0, which is inconsistent with the conda's cuda version. Because of this, I got a trouble installing the PYG. How to get the same nvcc 10.1 as the torch.version.cuda version?

Comment: `torch.version.cuda` is a hard compiled string in Pytorch. It is the CUDA version PyTorch was built against. Conda doesn't install nvcc so you likely have a 10.0 toolkit separately installed and an anaconda managed CUDA 10.1 runtime which conda installed for PyTorch to use

Comment: So that means there won't be conflict between two versions of nvcc when using pytorch in conda?

Comment: @talonmies Is there a way. to set the conda nvcc path to replace the default nvcc path?

Comment: As I said in my first comment, there is no "conda nvcc path" because the default anaconda packages don't install nvcc or most of the cuda toolkit. You only get the bare minimum redistributable runtime components and nothing else